# Update msgpack when unpacking

Tags: msgpack

I need to decode a msgpack buffer, update a value in optional field and encode it again to be send further.

Ideally I don't want to decode whole message and encode again just to update a field in options, to save on performance.

After decoding using `"unpacker->next(ObjHandle)"` I get optional field value as `msgpack::object_kv` but I can't find any API which will let me update value and it's size and update internal buffer.

Is it possible to update values in-place with msgpack::unpacker?